# iOS7 homescreen app seems to not use AppCache manifest

Tags: html, caching, ios7, cache-manifest

I had an application that worked perfectly on iOS6. The process is :

- Login
- Check/update the cache manifest
- Read all the pages from the cache (in order to work offline, and it worked).

  but since the iOS7 update, the cache manifest update itself correctly if needed, but it seems that no page is loaded from the cache...
- Page index is redirecting to login each time (maybe because of the server request)
- Offline mode does not working

I already try to change the name of the cache manifest to name it "cache.manifest"...

Please help me, i'm going to get crazy ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woooow... After lots of researches, I figured out the problem.

Instead of calling "login.aspx" the first time into safari (in order to create the webapp), I must call index.aspx which redirect me to the login page because I'm not logged.

Using this, the behavior of my webapp is normal (I cannot explain why...) and the cache manifest REALLY cache the webapp.

I can access offline and online.

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem... (iOS mystery)